# How do I get Siri to call Amy instead of Aimee?

Tags: iphone, siri, ios

I don't even have a phone number for Aimee.  Amy is even marked as a favorite. Whenever I say "Call Amy" then Siri says "I don't have a phone number for Aimee."

It was working with iOS 9.

iOS 10.1.1, iPhone 5,1.

Comment: Add Aimee or Amy's last name. Or are they also homophones?

Comment: They both have last names entered. I want to use just the first name to call.

Answer (score 5):

If both people are in your **Contacts**, you can give one, or both, a nickname.  When using Siri, you can refer to the person by nickname and Siri will know who you're talking about.

To add a nickname to a person:

1. Open the *Contacts* app
2. Tap the contact you want to view, then tap `Edit`
3. Scroll down and tap `add field -> Nickname`
4. Add a nickname and tap `Done`

To remove a nickname, just reverse the steps.  You can change the nickname at any time.

[Source](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202590)

Comment: I added the nickname Amy but it didn't work. I also tried the nickname Aimee  and that didn't work either.

Comment: The iPhone can't tell the difference in the spelling when the names sound the same.  Did you set each person up with a nickname that doesn't sound like the other person's nickname?  You can't use 'Amy' and 'Aimee' as nicknames because they sound the same to the iPhone.

Answer (score -1):

Not really a soultion, but would probably work anyway:

Roll with it - add Amy's phone number to Aimee's contact info!

Comment: Do we work for machines or do machines work for us?

Comment: @Chloe, sometimes I do wonder....